Reference: The midpoint of centroids of triangles $A_1A_2A_3$ and $B_1B_2B_3$ is the centroid of $C_1C_2C_3$, where $C_i$ is the midpoint of $A_iB_i$
Let $\triangle A_1A_2A_3$ and $\triangle B_1B_2B_3$ betwo  triangles; let the midpoint of line segment $A_1B_1$ be $C_1$, and similarly define $C_2$, $C_3$ cyclically.

In which research paper is it mentioned that centroid of triangle $\triangle C_1C_2C_3$ is midpoint of the centroids of $\triangle A_1A_2A_3$ and $\triangle B_1B_2B_3$?

Please note: I know the proof, as it can be easily proved by complex numbers, co-ordinate geometry, etc. I want a reference about where such things are mentioned.

This is such an immediate result, that I don't think you can find a research paper in the past 200 years that proves just that statement. If you want to cite a reference, you might want to look into a textbook.

Here is a possible reference for the "physics solution", https://www.jstor.org/stable/3029428, or rather theoretical mechanics, going back to a source from 1902. The theorem has as a corollary the fact that given a system of particles with masses $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_r$ which are placed at points $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_r$ in the space (with one, two, three, or more dimensions), then the centroid is kept in place if we replace some subsystem of particles by their centroid, where we place the total mass of the subsystem.
Application in our case.
Start with points of mass one placed in $A_1,A_2,A_3; B_1,B_2,B_3$. Let $G$ be  the centroid of this system.

We can regroup and obtain $G$ by replacing the subsystems $\{A_j,B_j\}$ with $C_j$ and a mass of two in each of them, $j$ among $1,2,3$, then taking the centroid of $\{C_1,C_2,C_3\}$,

or we can regroup and obtain $G$ by replacing the subsystems $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$, and $\{B_1,B_2,B_3\}$ with their centroids,  and a mass of three in each, then taking the centroid (mid point) of them.


